# Regex to match and replace BB code quote

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to match a string like this:

```
[quote12445555=Me]Some \n Quote[/quote12445555]
```

And replace it with this:

```
<blockquote>Some \n Quote</blockquote>
```

I had regex for this as follows:

```
!\[quote(\d+)=(\w+)\](.*|\r\n|\n)\[\/quote(\d+)\]!
```

Replaced by:

```
<blockquote>$3</blockquote>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not use the php bb code functions rather than creating your own.

Comment: Not everyone can install pecl extensions.

Comment: Beware for `[quote1=Me] ... [quote2=You] ... [/quote2] ... [/quote1]`

Comment: The bb extensions don't allow for processing of this and it won't generate the HTML that I want. Otherwise I would have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work in my tests:

```
\[quote[0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]((.|\n)*)\[/quote[0-9]+\]
```

try changing: `(.*|\r\n|\n)` to `(.|\r\n|\n)*`

does the forward slash need to be escaped? `\/`

My replace string was: `<blockquote>$1</blockquote>`

Comment: I did my tests using the Java.  You may need to tweak it for whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$quotes = preg_replace('%\[(quote\d+)=([^\]]+)\]([^[]+)\[/\1\]%', '<blockquote>$3</blockquote>', $quotes);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI the correct regex was:

```
'!\[quote(\d+)\=(\w+)\](.+?)\[\/quote(\d+)\]!is'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be `#\[quote(\d+)=(\w+)\](.+?)\[/quote\\1\]#is` :)